# How to integrate Scoreloop with PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, scoreloop

I'm writing a cross-platform game with PhoneGap (iOS + Android + Bada + WP7) and I would like to use Scoreloop for things like a shared leaderboard and in-app billing. How do I integrate Scoreloop and PhoneGap? I know I could write a plugin for it, but that means writing 4 plugins...is there something already made on the market?

Comment: Have you asked scoreloop to support PhoneGap?

Answer (score 1):

A late answer, and not the one you need right now, but Scoreloop has been shut down on December 2014. (And there was no WebWorks / Cordova / PhoneGap support at this time anyway.)